# NGINX directories inside root are not accessible

Tags: nginx

I cannot access to directories inside server's document root.
It throw 403 Forbidden error!

here is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
#################
# Custom config
################
#disable_symlinks off;


##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

server root directory map:

/var/www/html/index.php

```
<?php include 'folder/file.php';
```

/var/www/html/folder/file.php

```
<?php echo 'file included';
```

if I request http://localhost/index.php it respond me 'file included' but if I request directly for http://localhost/folder/file.php it says me 403 Forbidden!

Comment: Change your first `location` block to this, `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args`.

Comment: Is there an entry in the error log?

Comment: Thanks, added try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args and it works :)